# ORA-03113 using PDO

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

I have an internal intranet made in PHP and we had the Oracle server here, but it has been moved to an cloud server. Since that I'm having an issue.

If I execute a simple query from PHP like "select * from empresas" it executes normal, but if I try a more complicated query, with some joins and where clause, it gives the error ORA-03113. Trying to execute from PL/SQL Developer, this specific query takes something like 5 seconds to execute, it returns something like 15 rows only.

I have no acces to the Oracle logs, because this cloud is just one instance to us.

I think that maybe is a PDO configuration or maybe version that I need to configure/check to solve this problem, just don't know how to start.

The old Oracle server was a Windows server and the Oracle version was 12. The cloud is Oracle 11 and is a Linux server.

Here is the query:

```
`SELECT distinct
  ct.descricao MARCA, 
  e.nome EMPRESA, 
  vi.cod_item CODIGO, 
  i.descricao DESCRICAO, 
  igi.cod_grupo_interno CODTIPO, 
  igi.descricao TIPO, 
  ic.cod_curva CLASSEABC,
  v.cod_cliente COD_CLIENTE, 
  cd.nome NOME_CLIENTE,
  ci.descricao CID_CLIENTE, 
  ci.uf UF_CLIENTE,
  CASE WHEN cd.cpf<>' ' THEN 'F' ELSE 'J' END TIPO_CLIENTE,
  cl.descricao DESCTP_CLIENTE,
  SUM(vi.qtde) QTDE, 
  vi.preco_unitario PPUBLICO, 
  SUM(vi.qtde * vi.preco_unitario) FAT_BRT, 
  SUM(vi.TOTAL_DESCONTOS) DESCONTO, 
  SUM(vi.preco_liquido_final) FAT_LIQ, 
  SUM(vi.qtde * vi.preco_contabil) CUSTO, 
  SUM(vi.base_icms) BASE_ICMS, 
  SUM(vi.valor_icms) VLR_ICMS, 
  '0' VLR_COP,
  '0' ACRESCIMO, 
  SUM(vi.valor_pis + vi.valor_cofins) VLR_PCOF,
  SUM(vi.valor_ipi) VLR_IPI, 
  NULL VLR_MARGEM,
  v.controle|| '-' || v.serie NF, 
  TO_CHAR(v.emissao, 'DD/MM/YYYY') DTNF, 
  n.cod_natureza CODNATUREZA, 
  n.descricao NATUREZA, 
  eu.id_funcionario VENDEDOR, 
  eu.nome_completo FUNCIONARIO, 
  eu.nome LOGIN, 
  eu.cod_funcao TIPO_FUN, 
  'N' STATUS,
  v.numero_os OS,
  v.chassi_resumido VEICULO,
  cd.bairro BAIRRO_CLIENTE, 
  v.controle|| '-' || v.serie NOTA,
  pg.descricao CONDICAO_PG, 
  pg.cod_forma_pgto COD_CONDICAO, 
  os.tipo CD_TP_OS, 
  ost.descricao DS_TP_OS,
  '0' PERCUSTOOPER,
  ed.cod_empresa_departamento DEPARTAMENTO, 
  ic.custo_fornecedor VLRREPOSICAO
FROM vendas v
INNER JOIN venda_itens vi ON vi.cod_empresa = v.cod_empresa and vi.controle = v.controle
INNER JOIN itens_custos ic ON ic.cod_empresa = v.cod_empresa AND ic.cod_item = vi.cod_item AND ic.cod_fornecedor = vi.cod_fornecedor
INNER JOIN itens_fornecedor if ON if.cod_item = vi.cod_item AND if.cod_fornecedor = vi.cod_fornecedor
INNER JOIN fornecedor_estoque fe ON fe.cod_fornecedor = if.cod_fornecedor
INNER JOIN itens i ON i.cod_item = vi.cod_item
INNER JOIN itens_grupo_interno igi ON igi.cod_grupo_interno = i.cod_grupo_interno
INNER JOIN empresas e ON e.cod_empresa = v.cod_empresa
INNER JOIN empresas_usuarios eu ON eu.nome = v.vendedor
INNER JOIN empresas_funcoes ef ON ef.cod_funcao = eu.cod_funcao
INNER JOIN empresas_departamentos ed ON ed.cod_empresa = v.cod_empresa AND ed.cod_empresa_departamento = v.cod_empresa_departamento
INNER JOIN parm_sys p ON p.cod_empresa = v.cod_empresa
INNER JOIN concessionaria_tipo ct ON ct.cod_tipo_concessionaria = p.tipo_concessionaria 
INNER JOIN cliente_diverso cd ON cd.cod_cliente = v.cod_cliente AND cd.cod_empresa = v.cod_empresa
INNER JOIN clientes_tipo cl ON cl.cod_tipo = cd.cod_tipo
INNER JOIN cidades ci ON ci.cod_cidades = cd.cod_cidades
LEFT JOIN pagamento_venda pv ON pv.controle = v.controle AND pv.serie = v.serie
LEFT JOIN forma_pgto pg ON pg.cod_forma_pgto = pv.cod_forma_pgto
LEFT JOIN os ON os.cod_empresa = v.cod_empresa and os.numero_os = v.numero_os
LEFT JOIN os_tipos ost ON ost.tipo = os.tipo
LEFT JOIN natureza n ON n.cod_natureza = vi.cod_natureza and n.grupo = vi.grupo 
LEFT JOIN operacoes ops ON ops.cod_empresa = v.cod_empresa and ops.cod_operacao = v.cod_operacao
WHERE v.status <> '1' AND v.total_produtos > 0
AND (ops.grupo is null or ops.grupo = 2)
AND v.emissao >= to_date(SYSDATE-20)
AND i.COD_GRUPO_INTERNO <> 13
GROUP BY ct.descricao, e.nome, vi.cod_item, i.descricao, igi.cod_grupo_interno, igi.descricao, ic.cod_curva, v.cod_cliente, 
cd.nome, ci.descricao, ci.uf, CASE WHEN cd.cpf<>' ' THEN 'F' ELSE 'J' END, cl.descricao, vi.preco_unitario, vi.preco_contabil, 
v.margem, v.controle|| '-' || v.serie, TO_CHAR(v.emissao, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), n.cod_natureza, n.descricao, eu.id_funcionario, 
eu.nome_completo, eu.nome, eu.cod_funcao, v.numero_os,  v.chassi_resumido, cd.bairro, v.controle|| '-' || v.serie, 
pg.descricao,pg.cod_forma_pgto, os.tipo, ost.descricao, ed.cod_empresa_departamento, ic.custo_fornecedor`
```

Comment: First result in google: `ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel. Cause: The connection between Client and Server process was broken.` Doesn't look like a query issue to me.

Comment: *"I have no acces to the Oracle logs, because this cloud is just one instance to us."* - yeah but whoever administers the cloud has that access. So you need to talk to **them**, because you can't diagnose the ORA-03113 without knowing what's in the log. Certainly there's nothing we can do except admire how horrible that query is :)

Comment: So, I will try to ask for the Oracle logs to identify the problem... You have no idea of how not horrible this query is... I have another that are bigger than this one without joins, just all tables on the from clause with commas... (just for start)

Answer (score 0):

I asked the administers for Oracle logs, it gave me nothing, the administers saw that my query even got to there, then I tried a lot of things and finally my boss found an answer. He saw that the problem is the size of the package the PHP are sending through the VPN connection we have with the cloud. So the solution (at least for now) is add to PDO connection the size we need using: "(DESCRIPTION=(SDU=1400) ..." on the connection string.